# Odoo One2many relation with calendar.event object

Tags: odoo

I'm neewby in Odoo and I've a problem with a relationship One2many with calendar.event object. 
I've defined a new object "Investigation" like this:

```
class Investigation(models.Model):
    _name = 'investigation'
    calendar_event_ids = fields.One2many('calendar.event', 'investigation_id', help="Meetings")
```

and I've modified calendar.event object like this:

```
class CalendarEvent(models.Model):
    _name = 'calendar.event'
    _inherit = 'calendar.event'
    investigation_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='investigation', inverse_name='investigation_id', help="Investigation")
```

I've defined my object view:

```
...
<page string="Calendar">
    <group>
        <field name="calendar_event_ids" string="Meetings"></field>
    </group>
</page>
...
```

and this is the new calendar.event form:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="investigation_view_calendar_event_form">
    <field name="name">Calendar - Event Form</field>
    <field name="model">calendar.event</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="1"/>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="calendar.view_calendar_event_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <data>
            <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[1]" position="replace">
                <page string="Meeting Details">
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="start_date" string="Date" on_change="onchange_dates('start', start_date, stop_date, allday, True)" />
                        </group>
                    </group>
                    <field name="message_needaction" invisible="1"/>
                </page>
            </xpath>
        </data>
    </field>
</record>
```

Adding new calendar.event object to my object investigation I obtain the following error:

```
......\workspace\odoo\addons\calendar\calendar.py(47)calendar_id2real_id()
-> return calendar_id and int(calendar_id) or calendar_id
(Pdb)
```

In debug mode I saw that in method get_real_ids(ids) in calendar.py class I've an ids value like "u'one2many_v_id_92'", but I suppose that ids must be long type.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `inverse_name` on `investigation_id` on model `calendar.event`. Actually `calendar_event_ids` on model `investigation` has and needs the `inverse_name` parameter. You've set it correctly, because `inverse_name` is the second parameter on `One2Many` field definition.

Comment: ok, I've applied  your changes, but nothing is changed. Debug message "return calendar_id and int(calendar_id) or calendar_id" persist and gui remain blocked

Comment: I don't see other problems in your code. Seems to me, that Odoo can't handle virtual IDs on `calendar.event`. Could be a bug. Open an issue on [Odoo Issues](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues)